# Gremlin returning bad results

Tags: java, gremlin, janusgraph

I'm writing unit tests and verifying data that should be returned / created / updated ,etc within my JanusGraph backend.

I'm also verifying the results with a Gremlin terminal, but have noticed that entities that have been updated are not reflecting the changes in my terminal.  The same thing happens when the vertex is deleted.  It's no longer in the Graph, but my gremlin console returns results.

I've had coworkers run the same query's as myself to prove that the values are inconsistent.  Is there a way to sync Gremlin with the actual values in the Graph?

EDIT.  My code is committing.  I'm just using tinkerpop to verify the data.

Comment: Are you making sure to commit the transactions after you make changes? Until you commit the Tx, what you see, and what others looking at the graph see, will be out of sync.

Comment: The commit is in my Java code, I'm just inspecting with gremlin.  I issued ```g.tx().commit()``` and it is now returning the expected value.  Why would I have to issue a commit within tinkerpop when I didn't execute anything from it?

Comment: It could just be timing but without knowing more about your backend store, index, how you are connecting and other variables it's hard to know. Keep in mind that in the Gremlin console, queries you issue start a new transaction which will have a view of the graph. That Tx stays open until you explicitly close it. If the new items were added after you started using the console - or very close to at the same time, by issuing a `commit` or most likely a `rollback` also works, you are giving things a chance to get back into sync from a Tx point of view. As I said it could also be something else.

Comment: HBase is the storage engine I'm using.   Im just wondering why a search would run a writable transaction that would need a commit or rollback.  I guess I'll just issue a rollback after each search verification...

Answer (score 2):

JanusGraph have something called **Transactional Scope**. According to this concept,

All graph elements (vertices, edges, and types) are associated with the transactional scope in which they were retrieved or created. Under TinkerPop’s default transactional semantics, transactions are automatically created with the first operation on the graph and closed explicitly using commit() or rollback(). Once the transaction is closed, all graph elements associated with that transaction become stale and unavailable. However, JanusGraph will automatically transition vertices and types into the new transactional scope as shown in this example:

```
    graph = JanusGraphFactory.open("berkeleyje:/tmp/janusgraph")
    juno = graph.addVertex() //Automatically opens a new transaction
    graph.tx().commit() //Ends transaction
    juno.property("name", "juno") //Vertex is automatically transitioned
```

Edges, on the other hand, are not automatically transitioned and cannot be accessed outside their original transaction. They must be explicitly transitioned:

```
    e = juno.addEdge("knows", graph.addVertex())
    graph.tx().commit() //Ends transaction
    e = g.E(e).next() //Need to refresh edge
    e.property("time", 99)
```

May be this is happening with you.